# Replace NULL Values on Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
COL 1   | COL 2   | COL 3   | COL 4
entry1  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
NULL    | NULL    | entry1  | entry1  
entry2  | entry1  | entry1  | NULL
```

Output should be

```
COL_1   | COL_2   | COL_3   | COL_4
entry1  | EMPTY   | EMPTY   | EMPTY
EMPTY   | EMPTY   | entry1  | entry1  
entry2  | entry1  | entry1  | EMPTY
```

I would like to replace all the columns with a given string. In this example the string is 'EMPTY'.

I know there are functions like 'COALESCE(COL_1, 'EMPTY_STRING) AS COL_1'...
But I dont want to do COALESCE for every column. Is there a method where I can replace every NULL value in a whole table?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you need a coalesce for each column. (Or fix it in the presentation layer.)

Comment: Can't we build a function which takes an table and iterates through the columns using COALESCE?

Comment: then, you can use Dynamic SQL along with user_tab_cols dictionary view.

Comment: Can you please make an example?

Comment: You could also do it using Polymorphic Table Function (if your version supports them, take the ECHO example from LiveSQL as a starting point), and you will have to decide if you want to do that for all data types and then provide/decide a default value for each type.

Comment: SQL table is not a text file, it's a long-term persistency. There's no such daily routine as "replace all nulls within a table" that's why there's no such tool to perform this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of PL/SQL code which does what you explained. It presumes that all columns in table are `VARCHAR2` because you can't put 'EMPTY' into a `NUMBER` or `DATE` datatype columns. If you do have columns of different datatype in that table, filter them in cursor's `WHERE` clause.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     col1   VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     col2   VARCHAR2 (10)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test
  2     SELECT 'entry1', NULL FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL
  6     SELECT 'entry2', 'entry1' FROM DUAL;

3 rows created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
entry1

entry2     entry1
```

Procedure uses dynamic SQL to update NULL values with a string 'EMPTY':

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT column_name
  5                     FROM user_tab_columns
  6                    WHERE table_name = 'TEST')
  7     LOOP
  8        l_str :=
  9              'update test set '
 10           || cur_r.column_name
 11           || q'[ = 'EMPTY' where ]'
 12           || cur_r.column_name
 13           || ' is null';
 14
 15        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 16     END LOOP;
 17  END;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
entry1     EMPTY
EMPTY      EMPTY
entry2     entry1

SQL>
```

---

If you want to move that anonymous code into a procedure, then:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
entry1

entry2     entry1
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_empty (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3     l_str  VARCHAR2 (200);
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT column_name
  6                     FROM user_tab_columns
  7                    WHERE table_name = DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name))
  8     LOOP
  9        l_str :=
 10              'update '
 11           || par_table_name
 12           || ' set '
 13           || cur_r.column_name
 14           || q'[ = 'EMPTY' where ]'
 15           || cur_r.column_name
 16           || ' is null';
 17
 18  dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 19        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     p_empty ('TEST');
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
entry1     EMPTY
EMPTY      EMPTY
entry2     entry1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to define the function in that way, that it takes in a table?

Like the following:
SELECT * FROM FUNC_REMOVE_NULL(TEST_TABLE)

Comment: Function? Procedures are supposed to modify data in tables, not functions. See edited answer.